# Horizontal list of user controls (winforms)

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, horizontallist

I'm certain this can't be as complex as I'm finding it so far!

I'm trying to render a horizontal list of user controls. There will be a large number of them. So some form of Virtual list would be prefereable.

Each user control will contain an image and be selectable.

In Android/Flex/iOS this is trivial with their List Adapters, List Item Renderers etc... However in Win forms it seems very tricky indeed.

I've looked at ObjectListView setting the view mode to Tile. However there doesn't appear to be a way to render horizontally.

I've tried just populating a flow layout with my user controls. But the memory usage goes through the roof as it's loading images.

Comment: I'm sure there are other solutions, but I've implemented this in the past using `DataGridView` and was pleased with the result.

Comment: Just throwing it out there: WPF. It's trivial there too and IMO simply the best for these things (thanks to the Content concept). See if you can use it instead of WinForms.

Comment: There's already a fairly substantial amount of application relying on Win Forms. Including a VLC media player wrapper that relies on it. So WPF is out unfortunately!!

Answer (score 1):

You could use FlowLayoutPanel container control and set its WrapContents to false and FlowDirection to LeftToRight (which is default). ...and, probably, AutoScroll to true.

---

**EDIT**

As to going out of memory, think of simulating virtualization by handling Scroll event and creating/disposing controls as needed.

Comment: errr... that's embarrassing. pardon my lack of attention.

Answer (score 0):

Derive your own image control from `Control` and override `OnPaint` in order to draw the image yourself. Add a property for the path or name of a picture, but don't store the image itself in the control. Google for [custom control c#](http://www.google.com/search?q=custom%20control%20c#).

Use a cache for the images. A good data structure for this is a [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). This helps in keeping only a limited number of images in memory.